# Get an input file and print multiple output files after performing operations on array in perl

Tags: perl

Let us call the input file shouldIgo.txt. My input file looks like this.

Jakarta paris delhi singapore

hot cold wet

yes no cannotcomment

I want to generate multiple output files which have the information which says

output file 1 is

city: Jakarta

weather: hot

recommended? : yes

output file 2 will be

city: Jakarta

weather: hot

recommended? : no

and so on. City, weather and recommended are hard coded. totally there will be 4*3*3 files. containing all possible combinations. Each of these information needs to be stored in separate files. I think I need to use file handles and manipulate the array. I am not able to achieve the result. Any help on this direction will be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! You appear to be new to the site, so you're not expected to know all the rules yet, but I'll try to help you. The way you worded your post makes it sound like you expect someone to write this code for you. If that's not the case (and I hope it isn't), you should post the code you've worked on so far, along with an error message or a specific place where you're stuck. Please see [ask] a good question, how to create a [mcve], and take a [tour] to find out more about how [so] works.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for writing that way. It was my first post. I have however written the code. Hope it is beneficial to someone.

```
#! perl -slw
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;


open(my $in, '<', 'ocean_dummy')
or die "Cannot open input.txt: $!";

my @city = split ' ', <$in>;
my @temp = split ' ', <$in>;
my @note = split ' ', <$in>;

my $i = '01';
for my $city ( @city ) {
for my $temp ( @temp ) {
    for my $note ( @note ) {
        open 0, '>', 'out' .  $i++ or die $!;
        print 0 'city: ', $city;
        print 0 'weather: ', $temp;
        print 0 'recommended: ', $note;
        close 0;
    }
}
}
```